# Error while adding data to MS-SQL by using Asp.Net MVC-5 after hosting it in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, iis-6

When I am trying to add data to MS-SQL by using Asp.Net MVC-5 after hosting it in IIS,
I am getting the error :

`Cannot open database "database name" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.`

I am using Entity Framework for DB connection.

Comment: Thanks sir, it's worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issue with your connection string. don't use integrated security. provide user id password in connection string